# MyObj.prototype. vs this

Tags: javascript, oop

JS newb here so hope this is not a daft question.

When defining a custom object with methods what is the difference between, and pros/cons of, the following two approaches?

1 : Define methods within class definition using`this`.

```
function MyObj(){    
    this.doStuff = function(){    
        //method body    
    }    
}
```

2 : Define methods separately using `prototype`.

```
function MyObj(){    
}    

MyObj.prototype.doStuff = function()    
{    
    //method body    
}
```

I am messing about with it at the moment and both seem to work the same so I thought I'd find the difference before I head off on a track that is going to come back and bite me on the arse later :)

Cheers all

Answer (score 3):

When you use `this`, every instance of your "class" will have its own copy of the method.

When you use the `prototype`, all the instances will share that one copy of the method. Therefore, it's more efficient to declare methods on the `prototype`, since less memory will be required for each instance.

For example, create two instances of `MyObj`:

```
var o1 = new MyObj(),
    o2 = new MyObj();
```

If the `doStuff` method is declared in the constructor, each of those instances now has a copy of that method in memory. If it was declared on the `prototype`, they share that one copy. When you try to call it:

```
o1.doStuff();
```

There is no `doStuff` property on the instance itself, so we move up the prototype chain, to `MyObj.prototype`, where there is a `doStuff` method.

Answer (score 1):

Other than memory considerations, there's also performance considerations.

Defining properties on `this` in the constructor is [much slower](http://jsperf.com/local-vs-prototype-creation), but in terms of actually accessing those properties later, [locally defined properties have a slight performance advantage](http://jsperf.com/local-vs-prototype) since the JS engine doesn't have to walk up the prototype chain.

In other words, if you will create a small number of objects infrequently, it's better to define properties locally in the constructor (#1), but if you'll be creating many objects, use the `prototype` (#2).